# How to check in c++ noexcept(T + T), where T is template

Tags: c++, templates, operators, noexcept

How to c++ check in noexcept that the template parameter T defined through template will throw or not throw an exception during the operation+.
In fact, you need to check the addition T + T for throwing a possible exception. I wrote the following code: `noexcept(T + T)`, but, unfortunately, such code does not compile.

Comment: Which version of C++ are you asking about?

Comment: What you did in your previous question (`noexcept(std::declval<T>() + std::declval<T>())`) should compile. There might be issues with it for testing only rvalue or only lvalue operands, but I don't see why you changed it?

Comment: ```noexcept(std::declval<T>() + std::declval<T>())``` is correct code? I'm in training on how to do this check. But, unfortunately, the system does not accept my answer, so I doubted this code.

Comment: @TippaToppa Yes, it is valid code and you also used it in a correct way in your previous question. What is "the system"? Do you mean you got a compilation error with it?

Answer (score 3):

`T + T` is not a valid expression.  `T` is a type, and types do not have operators.  What you want are objects of type `T` and to add them together to see if that expression is `noexcept` or not.  You can do that like

```
noexcept(std::declval<T>() + std::declval<T>())
```

Comment: Note that `noexcept` is applied to functions. Which typically have parameters. Which typically have names that `noexcept` can already access. And typically, these parameters will involve at least one which is of type `T`. So `declval` is almost always unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using C++20, you can write a concept to check this:

```cpp
template<class T>
concept noexcept_addable = requires(T a)
{
    requires noexcept(a + a);
};
```

Note that it's `requires noexcept(a + a);`, not just `noexcept(a + a);`. The latter would just check that `noexcept(a + a);` is valid to compile, whereas the former actually requires that it evaluates to `true`.

You can see a demo of this concept [here](https://godbolt.org/z/1EG6YeTMM).